# How can I align at relation symbols within a cases environment?

Tags: tables, align, cases

I have used the following code in LaTeX -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \hline 
  { $X=y+z$}  & { 
   \parbox[c]{0.75\columnwidth}{
    $C_L = \begin{cases} 
        min\left[\left(Re\right),\: f(B)\right]\:;\: A<4\\   
        f(E)\:;\:4\le E<10\\
         -0.29\:;\: E\ge10
        \end{cases}$\\ 
    $f(E) = E^{3}-0.0159E^{2}-0.0204E+0.474$\\
  }
}\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

In the output, I would like the equals sign of `C_L` and `f(E)` to be aligned with each other. I have tried to use `align` environment, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help?

[image: imageoutput]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can push the `cases` content to the right the same amount as `f(E)` using

```
$\phantom{f(E)}\llap{$C_L$} = \begin{cases}
%...
```

The `l`eft over`lap` makes a right-aligned, zero-width box to not let `C_L` influence the spacing.

[image]

Ps. You may want to use `\min` instead of just typing `min` in math mode.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `align` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package. I see you load it anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \hline 
  { $X=y+z$}  & { 
   \parbox[c]{0.75\columnwidth}{
   \begin{align}
   C_L&= \begin{cases} 
        min\left[\left(Re\right),\: f(B)\right]\:;\: A<4\\   
        f(E)\:;\:4\le E<10\\
         -0.29\:;\: E\ge10
        \end{cases}\\ 
    f(E)&= E^{3}-0.0159E^{2}-0.0204E+0.474
   \end{align}
  }
}\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The ampersands before the equal signs set the characters that need to be aligned, meaning that if you used it in another place, the character that follows will be aligned.

And here's the output of the code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use of the `aligned` environment seems the simplest fix to me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \hline 
  { $X=y+z$}  & { 
   \parbox[c]{0.75\columnwidth}{
   \( \begin{aligned}
   C_L&= \begin{cases} 
        min\left[\left(Re\right),\: f(B)\right]\:;\: A<4\\   
        f(E)\:;\:4\le E<10\\
         -0.29\:;\: E\ge10
        \end{cases}\\ 
    f(E)&= E^{3}-0.0159E^{2}-0.0204E+0.474
   \end{aligned} \)
  }
}\tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

two things to notice:

- within a `\parbox`, the `aligned` environment needs to be put explicitly into math mode;
- the original example had more space at the bottom than at the top; this was caused by an extra `\\` after the last line, which has been removed here.

[image: output of example code]

Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment to Barbaras suggestion (the answer allows better formatting). Instead of the inner cases, I'd use `alignedat` in order to also align the conditions within the `cases`

```
\left\{
 \begin{alignedat}{2}
   &\min[(Re),\: f(B)]\:;&\quad A&<4\\   
   &f(E)\:; &4&\le E<10\\
   &-0.29\:; &E&\ge10
 \end{alignedat}
\right.
```

Also I've removed the `\left...\right` constructions from within the `\min` as they did not contribute anything.

Edit: Added visuals

[image]